# How to determine suitable Cysteine mutations?

Tags: mutations, protein-binding

In the lab, I'd like to generate a dimer of a protein via disulfide bonds. The interface between the two looks as follows:
[image: O3-33 interface]

Now, in the interface, there isn't any cystein I could use to dimerize the two, so I'll introduce some (bacterial transformation). But which place would be the best to introduce them? Probably not the alpha-helices or beta-sheets. But is there a general method to find the best linking site? Maybe there are program to calculate an energy minimum? Or is there a nice heuristic?

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAXxd.png)  a picture of a close-up of the interface.

Comment: Ive had success with [Disulfude by Design](http://cptweb.cpt.wayne.edu/DbD/), though it doesn't tell you how the suggested mutations will affect protein structure.

Comment: You need proper bioinformatics analysis to get predictions on this. Do molecular dynamics simulations for such calculation. One of most famous free tool is [GROMACS](http://www.gromacs.org/).